# Wordpress: Job Manager: How to modify Resume custom fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, resume

I have been trying to figure out a filter or action to modify Resume custom fields.
There is a documentation [here](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/resume-manager-editing-submission-fields/) about how to do it for resume core fields but not for custom fields.
If I use submit_resume_form_fields filter like

```
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields', 'remove_submit_resume_form_fields' );

function remove_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {
```

$fields only returns resume core fields but not the custom fields.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service but we can help you fix *specific* issues in your code. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it worked. So instead of using submit_resume_form_fields filter, I used submit_resume_form_fields_get_resume_data and it gave me all the fields (with custom fields as well). Unfortunately I could not find a documentation of this, I had to search the code. So the code goes like

```
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields_get_resume_data', 'remove_submit_resume_form_fields' );

function remove_submit_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['resume_fields']['custom_field_name'] );
}
```

I thought it might help someone!